# What will be the run time if a function is defined inside a program but is not called in main function?

Tags: c

I am doing all my assignments in a single .c file by writing functions, but now it seems that it affects the run time. Does it mean that if I do not call a function but define it then the function is also compiled and hence it slows down the program?

Comment: It's not clear what you are describing or asking. Adding a function should not greatly increase the compilation time. Do you mean actually the run time? Anyway, please provide a [mre] which illustrates what you are describing. Please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Yes your function will be compiled even if it's not called.

Comment: Why would compiling something extra affect the run time?

Comment: Please describe the duration you are describing. Is it from hitting the "build and run" button to the end of execution? Is it from starting the program (i.e. after building) to end of execution? Is it from "build" button to the point where an executable exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.
The only thing it affects is compile and link time and to some degree startup/load time (becauese of larger binary)

Most compilers will strip (i.e. remove) unused code when optimizations are turned on.

Comment: I think most compilers keep non-static code around.